# Are domain cPanel and hosting cPanel different?

Tags: cpanel

My website has a cpanel at www.mysitename.com/cpanel. Now as far as I know this is the domain cPanel and I can only moderate things that are on that domain or the website on that domain.

Now there is also another cPanel at my hosting provider's website that I call hosting cPanel. My question is, are they different? If they are, what is the difference?

Answer (score 3):

I think what you may be referring to is a "master cPanel" where you can view all of your individual cPanel accounts as well as do some more specific things to your web server. This is known as WHM (Web Host Manager). In most cases you as the web master will have a VPS or "re-seller hosting". You will create the clients cPanel account from your WHM panel.

Since you did not provide any specifics about who your hosting provider is, you could check with them to see if you have WHM, and where to log in.

Comment: Hello Mister! Thanks for answering. I bought the website from the designer. He gave me three passwords: WP-Admin, cPanel, and domain account. WP Admin is for Wordpress administration I know that. And domain registration is, well, domain registration. What got me confused is that my cPanel is at www.mywebsite.com/cPanel. I can moderate files on the domain there. But as far as I know, he also should've given me an account for the hosting service too. Am I wrong to assume that? Again to my knowledge, he can access hosting panel and see my files, which is risky for me. But am I wrong to assume it?

Comment: This makes sense now. It is very common for the webmaster to give you access to a cPanel account although you may rarely use it.

Comment: But shouldn't he also given me hosting service account too?

Comment: cPanel is the "hosting service account". This is where you setup your email addresses, manage your site database, etc.

Comment: Oh. I got a misconception about cPanel in my mind then. I thought I was supposed to say go to HostGator's website and log in and access to my site files, databases etc.

Comment: @JeremyC You might be able to access cPanel via different URLs, ie. via HostGator (possibly via SSL), your website domain (which may not be secure), etc. But cPanel is cPanel and should all point to the same thing.

Comment: @w3dk In the end, it has one password though, right?

Answer (score 2):

Ask your hosting provider, they'll know best ;)

Generally, a hosting provider using cPanel has three interfaces: cPanel (for website and domain management), WHM (for resellers) and a billing system such as WHMCS.

In the end though, all features should be the same. They're all cPanel.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks for answer. Can I ask something? If I have the www.sitename.com/cpanel password, can the person I bought the website from access my site files from another place? (I don't mean it as FTP or something but as another cPanel interface)

Comment: @JeremyC Sure! The cPanel interface provides a built-in file manager, yeah.  As long as a person has your cPanel password, they'll be able to access that interface. Your host probably doesn't have your cPanel login unless they login to it through their own management interface.

Comment: After making the website, he gave me the cPanel password and I changed it. That means I'm safe I guess then? Sorry for noobish questions by the way. I am just starting with all this :)

Comment: @JeremyC Got it! He probably won't have your password, but will be able to access your cPanel without a password.

Comment: Access? Like, beyond the login page? Isn't that risky for me?

Comment: If you're with a reputable hosting company, not really.